# How to refresh "onDraw()" every 100 millisecond or less to move "bitmap"

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to move "bitmap" from top to down and then from down to top.

I use "invalidate()" to refresh "onDraw()" after "y1" increases or decreases, everything working fine but "bitmap" movement is very slow.

I can increases or decreases y1 like "y1 += 15" but "bitmap" will move not smooth

I want refresh "onDraw()" every 100ms or less. 
How to do it?

[This screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yWUfQ.png)

```
package com.example.duc25.runningman  


import android.content.Context
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory
import android.graphics.Canvas
import android.graphics.Paint
import android.util.Log
import android.view.MotionEvent
import android.view.View
import android.widget.Toast
import java.util.*

class Man(contex: Context, var screenW: Float, var screenH: Float): View(contex){
    var bitmap1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, R.drawable.step1)
    var x1: Float = 0F
    var y1: Float = 0F
    var boolean1: Boolean = true

    override fun onTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent): Boolean{
        if(event.action === MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
            if(boolean1 == true){
                boolean1 = false
            }else{
                boolean1 = true
            }
        }

        return true
    }

    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas){
        set_X(canvas)

        if (boolean1) {
            if (y1 <= (screenH / 100) * 70){
                y1 += 1F
            }else{
                boolean1 = false
            }
        }else{
            if(y1 >= 0) {
                y1 -= 1F
            }else{
                boolean1 = true
            }
        }
        invalidate()
    }

    fun set_X(canvas: Canvas) {
        val paint = Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG)
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap1, x1, y1, paint)
    }
}
```

Comment: use ObjectAnimator / ValueAnimator

Comment: cannot set bitmap.translationY

Comment: what `translationY`? you mean `y1`?

Comment: cause i use ValueAnimator

Comment: val valueAnimation = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0f, -screenH)
        valueAnimation.addUpdateListener {
            val value = it.animatedValue as Float
            bitmap.translationY = value // cannot do this
        }

Comment: `y1 = value // can do this`

Comment: i will try it!!!

Comment: remove EVERYTHING from `onDraw` and leave only: `canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap1, x1, y1, null)`, in your update listener do: `y1 = value; invalidate();` thats all

Comment: great! it working, thank you so much!

Comment: your welcome, btw you can also use `ObjectAnimator`

Comment: ok i will read more document for it

Comment: in kotlin you can directly animate "y1" property I think but I'm not 100% sure

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `invalidate()`, you probably want to use [postInvalidateOnAnimation()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#postInvalidateOnAnimation()). This will trigger an animation at 60 fps, or ~ every 16 millis.

You could also use some sort of [postInvalidateDelayed()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#postInvalidateDelayed(long)) if you want a slower fps (you probably want 60 fps).

My guess you are getting lag because you are spamming the main thread with `invalidate()` repetitively. If you are still getting lag when using `postInvalidateOnAnimation()`, then what you are doing on each animation frame is too heavy, and you'll have to find a way to make it cheaper / faster.

**EDIT:** A few other tips.
1. You are creating the `Paint` every animation frame. That's bad. I recommend you move the `val paint = Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG)` into a property at the top of the class, i.e. with the `y1` and `x1` properties.
2. `bitmap1` can be `val` instead of `var`.

Comment: I remove "invalidate()" an use "postInvalidateOnAnimation()" but nothing changes